# Optimization of a convex target function with inequality constraints

Tags: real-analysis, optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I want to solve the following optimization problem:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{maximize} &\;\;\; \ln x_1+\ln x_2+\ln x_3+\ln x_4 \\
\text{s.t} &\;\;\; x_4\le4 \\
\text{and}&\;\;\; (5x_1+7x_3)/8\le 8 \\
\text{and}&\;\;\; x_3+4/7x_4\le 7 \\
\text{and}&\;\;\; x_1\le 5 \\
\text{and}&\;\;\; x_2\le 8 \\
\text{and}&\;\;\; (5x_1+8x_2)/11\le 11
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Each $x_i$ should be non-negative. Actually, since they are used as arguments of $\ln x_i$ they should be positive.

I've tried an approach using [Lagrange multipliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). As I was told, since there are feasible solutions and $\ln$ is a convex function, I should be able to find optimal solutions. However, let $f(x)$ denote our target function and $g(x):=\varphi(x)-C$ describe all the inequalities $\varphi(x)\le C$, s.t. they are fulfilled iff $g(x)\le 0$ (it's a little bit imprecise, but I'm sure you know what I mean).

What I've done now was writing down the following ten equations:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}f(x)+\sum_{k=1}^6\lambda_k\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}g_k(x) &= 0\;\;\;\;\;(i=1,\ldots, 4) \\
\lambda_kg_k(x)&=0\;\;\;\;\;(k=1,\ldots, 6)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I've tried to solve them and ended up with

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lambda_1 &=-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{4}{7}\lambda_3 \\
\lambda_2 &=-\frac{8}{33}-\frac{8}{7}\lambda_3 \\
\lambda_4 &=\frac{5}{7}\lambda_3+\frac{5}{8}\lambda_5-\frac{835}{2112} \\
\lambda_6 &=-\frac{11}{64}-\frac{11}{8}\lambda_5 \\
0 &=-\frac{25}{7}\lambda_3+5\lambda_4-\frac{25}{8}\lambda_5-\frac{313}{2112} \\
0 &=\frac{285}{56}\lambda_3-\frac{57}{8}\lambda_4+\frac{285}{64}\lambda_5+\frac{179}{176}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

As you may can see, the 3th and 5th equations cannot be fulfilled at the same time. So, something went wrong. In addition to a general procedure I would be very thankful if someone could recommend a computational way to calculate the maximum.

Comment: The multiplier $\lambda_i$ is non-zero only if the associated inequality constraint is fulfilled with equality (it is active). You have to try different combination of active/inactive constraints to determine a KKT point.

Comment: I would recommend you to use a numerical solver. Are you familiar with Matlab?

Comment: @Ert Yes, but I don't know how I can solve this problem with Matlab.

Comment: @daw For the sake of simplicity: Let's assume for a moment that all these inequalities were actually equalities. From my understanding, the procedure didn't change. So, even in this case I don't find a solution. Any idea?

Comment: then the assumption that all inequalities are active is false

Comment: @daw I'm unsure what you mean. If we assume that we deal with equalities, there are no inequalities which could be active. A feasible solution would need to fulfill all of them.

Comment: Since you have inequality constraints, you're really working with the [KKT conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) rather than Lagrange multipliers. But I don't see anything wrong with your original formulation (except that you're missing the conditions $g_k(x)\le0$, $\lambda_k\le0$, but that doesn't change the *equations*). So there must have been an error when you derived your final system of six equations.

Comment: In any case, I agree with the suggestion to just use a numerical solver such as CVX or the built-in [fmincon](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html).

Comment: @Rahul How would you use fmincon in this case? I'm unsure how to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a solution to your problem: Use the cvx interface for convex programming together with Matlab, see http://cvxr.com/cvx/. You have to download some software and read the user's guide. It's simple.